# subtract 2 colums from each other

Tags: r

I need to make a new column PRICE minus MEAN_PRICE_DISTRICT. I have tried this, but it does not work? how to subtract 2 columns from each other, my idea was probably too simple :-)

```
tekoopl %>%  group_by(DISTRICT)%>%  mutate(new_column= PRICE - MEAN_PRICE_DISTRICT)
```

I have only just started with R ;-)
(I am currently using the packages dplyr and tidyr)

```
A tibble: 19,073,620 x 17
# Groups:   PRICE [24,547]
   ID          PRICE DATE  POSTCODE TYPE  OLD_NEW DURATION PAON  SAON  STREET LOCALITY TOWN  DISTRICT COUNTY PPD   STATUS
   <chr>       <int> <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>   <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>    <chr> <chr>    <chr>  <chr> <chr> 
 1 {CCA5ACA8~ 562500 2014~ SE1 0FT  F     Y       L        ROSL~ APAR~ EWER ~ NA       LOND~ SOUTHWA~ GREAT~ A     A     
 2 {CCA5ACA8~ 562500 2014~ SE1 0FT  F     Y       L        ROSL~ APAR~ EWER ~ NA       LOND~ SOUTHWA~ GREAT~ A     A     
 3 {CCA5ACA8~ 562500 2014~ SE1 0FT  F     Y       L        ROSL~ APAR~ EWER ~ NA       LOND~ SOUTHWA~ GREAT~ A     A     
 4 {CCA5ACA8~ 562500 2014~ SE1 0FT  F     Y       L        ROSL~ APAR~ EWER ~ NA       LOND~ SOUTHWA~ GREAT~ A     A     
 5 {CCA5ACA8~ 562500 2014~ SE1 0FT  F     Y       L        ROSL~ APAR~ EWER ~ NA       LOND~ SOUTHWA~ GREAT~ A     A     
 6 {CCA5ACA8~ 562500 2014~ SE1 0FT  F     Y       L        ROSL~ APAR~ EWER ~ NA       LOND~ SOUTHWA~ GREAT~ A     A     
 7 {CCA5ACA8~ 562500 2014~ SE1 0FT  F     Y       L        ROSL~ APAR~ EWER ~ NA       LOND~ SOUTHWA~ GREAT~ A     A     
 8 {C1C0D748~ 272000 2014~ N19 3DY  F     N       L        23    NA    PARTI~ NA       LOND~ ISLINGT~ GREAT~ A     A     
 9 {C1C0D748~ 272000 2014~ N19 3DY  F     N       L        23    NA    PARTI~ NA       LOND~ ISLINGT~ GREAT~ A     A     
10 {C1C0D748~ 272000 2014~ N19 3DY  F     N       L        23    NA    PARTI~ NA       LOND~ ISLINGT~ GREAT~ A     A     
# ... with 19,073,610 more rows, and 1 more variable: mean_price <dbl>
    enter code here

A tibble: 339,500 x 4
# Groups:   DISTRICT [34]
    PRICE DISTRICT       mean_price MEAN_PRICE
    <int> <chr>               <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 562500 SOUTHWARK         779138.    779138.
 2 272000 ISLINGTON         897315.    897315.
 3 350000 LEWISHAM          451338.    451338.
 4 331000 NEWHAM            416543.    416543.
 5 534250 LAMBETH           638344.    638344.
 6 530000 LEWISHAM          451338.    451338.
 7 855000 WANDSWORTH        778023.    778023.
 8 242500 ENFIELD           448493.    448493.
 9 685000 ISLINGTON         897315.    897315.
10 250000 WALTHAM FOREST    428074.    428074.
# ... with 339,490 more rows
```

Comment: Hi Silvia, it is very useful if you also upload datasets, or at least a few rows. You can do that by running the code `dput(head(tekoopl))` and `dput(head(dfl07))`. Copy the output as a code in your question.

Comment: Can you also copy the error message?

Comment: the Error says:  object 'PRICE' not found
so I altered  PRICE to DISTRICT in group_by(DISTRICT) but then I get the same Error

Comment: It is hard to help if we cannot see your data. follow my first comment and upload datasets.

Comment: I tried to do as you said, But that also doesn't work. dput(head(tekoopl)) Sorry, it's my first days of R I'll try again. Thanks for your help!

Comment: First table is: tekoopl
second table is: dfl07

Comment: Ok. Now it is easier to say. Let's start at the beginning: 

Your code: 
`tekoopl %>%  group_by(DISTRICT)%>%  mutate(new_column= PRICE - MEAN_PRICE_DISTRICT)`

is looking for column "MEAN_PRICE_DISTRICT inside dataset `tekoopl`. But there is no such a column.

Comment: Can you try: `tekoopl <- tekoopl %>% group_by(DISTRICT)%>% mutate(new_column= PRICE - mean_price) `

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the result to tekoopl:

```
tekoopl <- tekoopl %>% group_by(DISTRICT)%>% mutate(new_column= PRICE - MEAN_PRICE_DISTRICT)
```

Comment: Sorry it took me so long, but my R Studio gievs me back an Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.4 Gb. I somehow have now a storage problem in R Studio. It's making me crazy pfffff Thanks for you're help anyway :-)

Comment: It's working, thank you so much for all your help! You've made my day :-)

Comment: You are welcome :-)